# LOSS not changeing in very simple KERAS binary classifier

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification

I'm trying to get a very (over) simplified Keras binary classifier neural network running without success. The LOSS just stays constant. I've played around with Optimizers (SGD, Adam, RMSProp), Learningrates, Weight-Initializations, Batch Size and input data normalization so far.

Nothing changes at all. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? Here is the code:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD

data = np.array(
    [
        [100,35,35,12,0],
        [101,46,35,21,0],
        [130,56,46,3412,1],
        [131,58,48,3542,1]
    ]
)

x = data[:,1:-1]
y_target = data[:,-1]

x = x / np.linalg.norm(x)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(3, input_shape=(3,), activation='softmax', kernel_initializer='lecun_normal',
                bias_initializer='lecun_normal'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer='lecun_normal',
                bias_initializer='lecun_normal'))

model.compile(optimizer=SGD(learning_rate=0.1),
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x, y_target, batch_size=2, epochs=10,
          verbose=1)
```

Comment: Softmax definition is: all neurons sum 1. What happens when you have 1 neuron? Yes, it's always 1

Comment: Use `"sigmoid"`

Comment: why `x = data[:,1:-1]` and not `x = data[:,:-1]`?

Comment: Also, the middle layer, `model.add(Dense(3, input_shape=(3,), activation='softmax',, kernel_initializer='lecun_normal', bias_initializer='lecun_normal'))` why did you set this to SoftMax? It's quite strange to have SoftMax in the middle. Have you tried `relu` or `sigmoid`, etc. ?

Comment: hey thanks folks! I was confusing softmax and sigmoid ... late night work maybe ... it's fixed now and works like a charm! will update my answer below for reference

Comment: @Geeocode because the 1st column is a part ID, the other three are measurements

Comment: created a little testimonial to you guys! https://youtu.be/aQJcK0oFnEw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Softmax** definition is:

```
exp(a) / sum(exp(a)
```

so when you use with a single neuron you will get:

```
exp(a) / exp(a) = 1
```

That is why your classifier doesn't work with a single neuron.

You can use **sigmoid** instead in this special case:

```
exp(a) / (exp(a) + 1)
```

Furthermore **sigmoid** function is for two class classifiers. **Softmax** is an extension of sigmoid for multiclass classifers.

For the first layer you should use **relu** or **sigmoid** function instead of softmax.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working solution based on the feedback I got

```
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.utils import to_categorical

data = np.array(
    [
        [100,35,35,12,0],
        [101,46,35,21,0],
        [130,56,46,3412,1],
        [131,58,48,3542,1]
    ]
)

x = data[:,1:-1]
y_target = data[:,-1]

x = x / np.linalg.norm(x)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(3, input_shape=(3,), activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer=SGD(learning_rate=0.1),
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x, y_target, epochs=1000,
          verbose=1)
```